# How to edit the url to log out of ApostropheCMS

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I'm working on a particular strategy to login OAuth2 to ApostropheCMS. After logging into the system, I need to close the session through the url of the identity server that allows me to do the OAuth2 flow.

Instead of using http://localhost:3000/logout, use http://localhost:port/auth/oauth2/logout. But I can't find where to edit the url using the log out link in ApostropheCMS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are saying that you don't need to duplicate the logout functionality (you already did that), you need to change the logout link in the admin bar. Fortunately there is a good way to do that.

Like most modules, the `apostrophe-login` module adds its admin bar buttons in a method called `addAdminBarItems`. That method looks like this:

```
    self.addAdminBarItems = function() {
      var items = [];
      var key;
      if (self.options.resetKnownPassword) {
        key = self.__meta.name + '-reset-known-password';
        self.apos.adminBar.add(key, 'Change Password', null);
        items.push(key);
      }
      key = self.__meta.name + '-logout';
      self.apos.adminBar.add(key, 'Log Out', null, { last: true, href: '/logout' });
      items.push(key);
      if (items.length > 1) {
        self.apos.adminBar.group({
          label: 'Account',
          items: items,
          last: true
        });
      }
    };
```

We can override it to suit our needs.

Create `lib/modules/apostrophe-login/index.js` at project level. Do not copy and paste the whole thing from node_modules, this is never necessary, we are overriding one method here. Apostrophe will automatically see that and apply our changes to the original.

Here's what the file will look like:

```
// in lib/modules/apostrophe-login/index.js of your project
module.exports = {
  construct: function(self, options) {
    self.addAdminBarItems = function() {
      key = self.__meta.name + '-logout';
      self.apos.adminBar.add(key, 'Log Out', null, { last: true, href: '/anywhere/you/want/it/to/go' });
    };
  }
};
```

This will replace the method we need to change, without altering anything else.

Comment: This is more suitable for i need to do. Thank you

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood. This is definitely better.

Answer (score 0):

There's not currently a way to edit the log out route path. The [callback on that route is fairly simple](https://github.com/apostrophecms/apostrophe/blob/820f4af761d4e92b314534cb694fb87d4aa246a7/lib/modules/apostrophe-login/index.js#L819-L832), however, so it might be fairly easy to simply write your own route that does the same thing.

```js
self.apos.app.get('/logout', function(req, res) {
  return req.session.destroy(function(err) {
    if (err) {
      self.apos.utils.error(err);
    }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```